# C# Json Convert any dynamic object to key value pairs

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, json.net

I am writing a tool that will take an inbound Json object, and convert it to 
key-value records (sometimes called flattening, maybe).  The aim is to avoid the tool breaking if it gets a very large or very nested Json object, so I would like to avoid recursion.

An example object might be like this (below), containing nested arrays, empty values, you name it, literally any legal json...

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "isAlive": true,
  "age": 25,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10021-3100"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "212 555-1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "office",
      "number": "646 555-4567"
    },
    {
      "type": "mobile",
      "number": "123 456-7890"
    }
  ],
  "children": [],
  "spouse": null
}
```

The desired output for the object above would be a key-value pair for every element of the object...

```
Key                     Value
/firstName              "John"
/lastName               "Smith"
/isAlive                "true"
/age                    "25"
/address
/address/streetAddress  "21 2nd Street"
/address/city           "New York"
/address/state          "NY"
/address/postalCode     "10021-3100"
/phoneNumbers
/phoneNumbers/1/
/phoneNumbers/1/type    "home"
/phoneNumbers/1/number  "212 555-1234"
/phoneNumbers/2/
/phoneNumbers/2/type    "office"
/phoneNumbers/2/number  "646 555-4567"
/phoneNumbers/3/
/phoneNumbers/3/type    "mobile"
/phoneNumbers/3/number  "123 456-7890"
/children
/spouse
```

I have the example object above in memory as a dynamic object, imported using Newtonsoft's JSON class.  Just to re-iterate, the ideal solution would not involve recursion, as a blown stack would be bad.  Thanks for any help forthcoming.

Comment: would the Nuget package newtonsoft json help? sounds llike they have already written your tool for you https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: If you blow your stack on recursion in your JSON, I'd say the JSON is worse than your blown stack. Anyway, I don't see any code in your question, no indication of what you have done yourself, and it feels like you are asking us to write you a piece of code...

Comment: @Aaron.S - Yep, I'm using it.  I have the string converted to a dynamic object, but the object structure is not known, so the question is how do I visit every node of a dynamic json object.  Thanks for the post.

Comment: @oerkelens - It is not my Json, this is a tool to convert any unknown Json.  Using recursion would expose tool users to a Stack Overflow.  It would also be a weak point for a malicious attack.  I get it that you think I am trying to scam some free code work, but in fact I am stuck on how to walk a dynamic json object.  I will find out by trial and error, but I thought an SO post would give me clues.  My current code just loads a string to a Json object (dynamic parsedJsonObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json); ).  Q: How to walk this object...

Comment: @oerkelens stay on topic.  your 'piece of code complaint' is unnecessary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);

var result = obj.Descendants()
    .OfType<JProperty>()
    .Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(p.Path,
        p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array || p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object
            ? null : p.Value));

foreach (var kvp in result)
    Console.WriteLine(kvp);
```

It gives you:

```
[firstName, John]
[lastName, Smith]
[isAlive, True]
[age, 25]
[address, ]
[address.streetAddress, 21 2nd Street]
[address.city, New York]
[address.state, NY]
[address.postalCode, 10021-3100]
[phoneNumbers, ]
[phoneNumbers[0].type, home]
[phoneNumbers[0].number, 212 555-1234]
[phoneNumbers[1].type, office]
[phoneNumbers[1].number, 646 555-4567]
[phoneNumbers[2].type, mobile]
[phoneNumbers[2].number, 123 456-7890]
[children, ]
[spouse, ]
```

I believe you will be able to make `Replace` in the path.

Comment: This is perfect!  To help those who come here looking for the full answer, I had to add using statements for Newtonsoft.Json.Linq and System.Linq.  I also had to use  Regex.Replace(key, "\\[(\\d+)\\]", delimiter + "$1");  to remove brackets, and simple string replace "." for delimiter, where delimiter is character(s) like forward slash, selected by user.  Great answer, many thanks, hope it helps other people out too.

Comment: how to identify rows and columns in result object?