# Update a json file containing variables from another json file in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a json config file with values as variables. I want to replace these variables with actual values that are stored in another json file.

Source data json file:

```
{
  "person": {
    "id": 15305,
    "gender": "Male",
    "dob": "1958-10-31T00:00:00",
    "name": {
      "id": 80587,
      "first": "John",
      "last": "Dominick"
    }
  },
  "ethnicity": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "display": "Not Hispanic or Latino",
      "kbEthnicity": null
    }
  ],
  "race": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "display": "Black"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "display": "Other Race"
    }
  ]
}
```

Destination data json file:

```
{
  "dryRun": "true",
  "person": {
    "firstName": "[person.name.first]",
    "lastName": "[person.name.last]",
    "dateOfBirth": "[person.dob]",
    "gender": "[person.gender]",
    "race": "[race]"
  }
}
```

Final json file that I want:
{
"dryRun": "true",
"person": {
"firstName": "John",
"lastName": "Dominick",
"dateOfBirth": "1958-10-31T00:00:00",
"gender": "MALE",
"race": "Black, Other Race"
}
}

Here is the code that I wrote using the following SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569434/c-sharp-json-convert-any-dynamic-object-to-key-value-pairs) that reads both files and is able to extract the correct values from the source file, but I am stuck on what is the best way to create a final json file.

```
public static void  Main(string[] args)
{
    var sourceJson = File.ReadAllText("./sourcedata.json");
    var srcObj = JObject.Parse(sourceJson);
    var destJson = File.ReadAllText("./destinationdata.json");
    var destObj = JObject.Parse(destJson);

    var result = destObj.Descendants()
        .OfType<JProperty>()
        .Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(p.Path,
            p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array || p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object
                ? null : p.Value));

    foreach (var kvp in result)
    {
        var isVariable = kvp.Value == null ? false : Regex.IsMatch(kvp.Value.ToString(), @"^\[.*?\]$");
        if (isVariable)
        {
            var variable = Regex.Replace(kvp.Value.ToString(), @"[\[\]]+", "");
            Console.WriteLine($"Key: {kvp.Key}  Value: {kvp.Value}  Updated: {srcObj.SelectToken(variable)}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key: {kvp.Key}  Value: {kvp.Value}");
        }
    }               
}
```

Another issue that I want to solve is how to concatenate the values if there is an array? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As a fellow C# user I quite regularly encounter these kinds of JSON processing tasks on web projects which are often also one-offs; i.e. once the result JSON file is done, so is the code. I personally use node.js for that kind of task as JS is certainly well suited to processing JSON with pretty minimal fuss. Lots of variables though e.g. do you know JS etc, but just a suggestion anyway.

Comment: @LukeBriggs I would agree with you, but JSON is becoming a universal format, and all languages are getting better equipped with the libraries to process them. I would have used JS but I am stuck right now to C# for this task as it is part of an existing web API code that I am trying to update. But, I hear you.

Answer (score 0):

High level: You need two POCO objects: one to deserialize your source json (with the values), and one to serialize to your destination json.

You read in the source, deserialize to the source poco, translate from source poco to destination poco, and then serialize *that* as destination json.

I think that's much more straightforward than working with `JObject`s, etc.

Here is a slightly simplified version of your objects:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = @"{""person"":{""name"": {""first"": ""John"",""last"": ""Dominick""}}}";

        var objA = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Source.MyObject>(json);
        Console.WriteLine("FirstName: " + objA.Person.Name.FirstName);
        
        var objB = new Destination.MyObject(objA);
        var outJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objB);
        Console.WriteLine(outJson);
        
    }
}
public class Source{
    public class MyObject
        {
            [JsonProperty("person")]
            public Person Person { get; set; }
        }
    public class Person
        {
            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public Name Name { get; set; }
        }
    public class Name
        {
            [JsonProperty("first")]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("last")]
            public string LastName { get; set; }
        }
}

public class Destination{
    public class MyObject{
        public MyObject(Source.MyObject sourceObject){
            Person = new Person();
            Person.FirstName = sourceObject.Person.Name.FirstName;
            Person.LastName = sourceObject.Person.Name.LastName;
        }

        [JsonProperty("person")]
        public Person Person {get;set;}
    }

    public class Person
    {
        [JsonProperty("firstName")]
        public string FirstName {get;set;}

        [JsonProperty("lastName")]
        public string LastName {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Output:

> FirstName: John
> {"person":{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Dominick"}}

see:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/0V4pEO

Comment: thank you for the prompt response. I missed one important aspect and that is the son strings are not fixed, as mentioned in the post that these jsons are the configs, so we can have different jsons. I can't use POCO unfortunately.